# Jquery input Event doesn't fire

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add this to an input field so whenever a user types or pastes something, an alert appears on the webpage. But it doesn't fire('code' is the id of the inputfield):

```
var codeInput = document.getElementById('code');
    $('#code').on('input', function () {
        window.alert(codeInput.value);
    });
```

Comment: Why are you mixing js and jquery? `$('#code').on('input', function () {
        alert($(this).val())
    }); `

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your html is ok this will work:

```
$('#code').on('input', function () {
    alert($(this).val())
});
```

I say assuming because if the html is dynamic you may need a different approach, like this:

```
$(document).on('input', '#code', function () {
    alert($(this).val())
});
```

[Have a look at this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gz5mjmh0/)

Comment: this is the input in html :     <input type="text" class = "undone" id="code" maxlength="4">

Answer (score 0):

`var codeInput = document.getElementById('code');`

This line, when encountered while execution of the JavaScript, will get the reference to the element with id `code` and store it in codeInput. This value will NOT update once it has been assigned.

```
$('#code').on('input', function () {
        window.alert(codeInput.value);
    });
```

This is an event handler. After it has been registered once, it will be executed everytime element `code` will have an input.

But you are trying to alert the value of `codeInput`, which has been assigned a value before, **AND NOT UPDATED**.

This should work (Get the reference to the current state of the element, and then call its value)

```
$('#code').on('input', function () {
    alert($(this).val())
});
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery does not have input event, you can use below code

```
var codeInput = document.getElementById('code');
    $('#code').on('input', function () {
        window.alert(codeInput.value);
    });
```